# Mistake syncrhonization direction - Unison ; deleted all my files

Tags: unison

I put the bad direction in Unison for synchronizing my external hard drive and a folder on my computer.

So it seems to have deleted all my external drive files.

Is there a way in Unison to revert the change.

Comment: How did you lose 3+ years of work by a single backup command? Was it the first time in 3+ years you perform a backup? If you do it daily, you can lose 1 day of work.... that's what I mean

Comment: that is the funny part. I had a backup on disk A and disk B (external hard drive). I lost disk A a few days before. so i thought "i'm going to use unison to copy the files from disk B to (new) disk C" (don't know why i haven't just CTrl+C, CTrl+V), but i made disk C => disk B. but fortunately my backup on disk B was very recent so testdisk recovered almost all my files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think so. I'm sorry for your loss. Your best bet is to use some file-recovery software independent of Unison. For the future, note Unison's support for [keeping backups](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Ebcpierce/unison/download/releases/stable/unison-manual.html#backups).

Answer (score 0):

Unmount your external hard drive.

Install testdisk and follow [https://vitux.com/how-to-recover-deleted-files-in-ubuntu-through-testdisk/][these instructions] to recover your files.

Comment: that's what i've done, thx you for the advice.